# Guaranteed message sending for messages of different priority for different modules

Tags: c#, design-patterns, performance, message-queue

We have created a message que system using priority messages. The idea behind this is as follows:

- We have a list of clients.
- All clients know if (and what kind of priority) messages they have available for sending.
- A client needs to send their higher priority message first.
- All clients need to keep sending, if there are clients with lower priority messages these clients also need time to send but higher priority is still more important.

We have the following mechanism:

1. We look for the client that is next in line with a priority message. We send send this high priority message.
2. We look (different counter) for the next in line with any message priority doesn't matter. We send this message.

For example in step 1 we find Client b to be the first to have a high priority message and we send it.

Then step 2 finds Client A to have a low priority message and we send this message.

Then back to step 1. Client B still has an other Priority message but we are going for the next one so all clients will ave the opportunity to send so Client C's high priority message is now send.

Then step 2 again, We have send a message for client A so we are now going for the next Client which is B, as we said Client B still has a high priority message so we send this message.

This keeps going on and on and on.

So my question: is this the best way to do it? Are there patterns or ways to do this in a better way? (maybe more efficient)

Comment: "several thousands" doesn't seem like much. How big are the messages?

Comment: There are already message queue brokers that exist. Have you looked at those products? The terminology may vary between implementations. The broker is the server that holds queues and topics. Queues deliver messages to one recipient, topics to all connected instances. Persistence allow clients to look back on messages that were published before they connected.

Comment: @Euphoric well several thousands times 1 thousand modules still is 1 million messages.

Comment: @VincentAdvocaat Still not enough to be considered a problem on modern hardware.

Comment: @ThomasOwens no, but i will surely look into those thank you

Comment: @Euphoric yes that is what i thought, but with our current implementation this takes a hell of a lot of time (I've heard co-workers say it takes over half an hour in the field for 1 million messages (of about 300 bytes/per message).

So yeh the implementation (which had been made a few years ago) just isn't done correctly. (It was something one of my co-workers came up with in his spare time)

Comment: Is this supposed to be in-process or inter-process communication?

Comment: @Euphoric I believe in-process communication, though I am a bit weary of it's definition, I'll put our current use case in the question.

Comment: What values the priorities can be and what do you mean "does not guarantee equal distribution"?

Comment: Many of the problems you're describing are solved by existing Message Brokers.    I have personally had a lot of success using RabbitMQ https://www.rabbitmq.com/ which supports all of the things you describe (either directly, or using one of the officially supported plugins), and has a C# Client library;  but there are other brokers out there as well.    I'd suggest you investigate Rabbit as well as other broker implementations (e.g. ActiveMQ, Kafka).